# Decreasing the height of the menubar using css

Tags: asp.net, css

I am new to css so can you please suggest how to decrease the height of menubar.

In visual studio 2010, i opened a new project and selected ASP.Net Website.
in that i have to change the width of the menubar from

[image]

to

[image]

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
```

Here is the css
[CSS](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_E1xtFQcbXdR25QVzlmM3hjNEU)
 & Here is the page source [Pagesource](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_E1xtFQcbXdQ3RtWUZNLS1HNGs)
It shows correctly in designer but when i run the project the width increases!!!

When i'm opening in firefox, it opens correctly and if i do in chrome the space is increased

Comment: What do you want to decrease ,width or height?

Comment: The designer's view matches to actual browser output very rarely. So don't decide by looking at the designer. Please provide the mark up and try to use fire bug to know more about the problem with  UI.

Comment: @freebird I want to decrease the height. Please compare the two images

Comment: @Krishna We cannot help you without viewing the markup.Can you please post it?

Comment: @freebird it's a default Visual Studio template.  It's not that easy to reproduce :S

Comment: @KrishnaThota the css you posted is good, but the HTML is not.  What you posted is the pre-generated code.  Try this:  Open the web page in a browser and viewing the source.  then post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me hours to get VS Web Developer free version on my computer. :\  I remembered having this problem before and I know I figured out how to fix it before too.  Basically it has to do with one of the default stylings conflicting with the layout.  There's a couple of hidden anchor tags in the `asp:Menu` control.  To fix it, you can simply add this style rule to your default sheet (under Tab Menu):

```
.hideSkiplink a
{
    display:none;
}
```

I don't know what those links are used for, but if you are not using at the time, this style rule will correct the issue.